# jquery reveal iframe with changed src when select option is chosen

Tags: javascript, jquery

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <select class="changer">
        <option value="http://stackoverflow.com">StackOverflow</option>
        <option value="http://google.com">Google</option>
        <option value="http://yahoo.com">Yahoo</option>
        <option value="http://twitter.com">Twitter.com</option>
    </select>
    <iframe src="http://stackoverflow.com"></iframe>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
    <select class="changer">
        <option value="http://stackoverflow.com">StackOverflow</option>
        <option value="http://google.com">Google</option>
        <option value="http://yahoo.com">Yahoo</option>
        <option value="http://twitter.com">Twitter.com</option>
    </select>
    <iframe src="http://stackoverflow.com"></iframe>
</div>
```

my jQuery:

```
$('.changer').change(function () {
    $(this).next('iframe').attr('src', this.value);
});
```

and CSS:

```
.wrap {
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}
iframe {
    width:100%;
    height:500px;
display:block;
}
```

This changes the src of the iframe when the select is clicked. how can i initially hide the iframe until something is clicked? I tried using fadein/fadeout but that doesn't work all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `iframe` elements to initially be `display:none`, e.g:

```
iframe {
    width:100%;
    height:500px;
    display:none;
}
```

and then use [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) (which is equivalent to setting an element's `display` property to `block`):

```
$(this).next('iframe').show().attr('src', this.value);
```

To show the relevant `iframe` on change.

<kbd>[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/5eM5D/)</kbd>

---

To fade it in instead of just showing it, you'd just use jQuery's [`fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) method instead:

```
$(this).next('iframe').fadeIn().attr('src', this.value);
```

<kbd>[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/5eM5D/1/)</kbd>